# functions.php template_redirect breaks site

Tags: php, wordpress, function, action

I used the function below in an earlier WordPress installation and that worked fine there. Now I want to use it in another installation but there I get a white screen.

If I take away the action below, he will.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'when_a_review_gets_submitted' );
```

but then the function no longer works as it should. He would have to retrieve the page_ID and the rest of the function would have to be executed.

Someone an idea why the current function no longer works?

This is the complete function:

```
function when_a_review_gets_submitted ($review, $post_id) {

// Set up the objects needed
$hosting_provider_query = new WP_Query();
global $post;
$hosting_pagina_titel = $post->post_title;  
$search_all_pages = $hosting_provider_query->query(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    //Only get pages where custom field 'name_hosting_provider' equals Page title
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'naam_hosting_provivder',
            'value' => $hosting_pagina_titel,
            'compare'   => '='
        ),

    ),
));

// Loop through all pages and find Page's children
$loop_through_all_child_pages = get_page_children( get_the_ID(), $search_all_pages );

// Loop through everything we got back
if(!empty($loop_through_all_child_pages)){
    foreach($loop_through_all_child_pages as $child_page){
        // get the ID of each childpage
        $get_child_page_ID = $child_page->ID;
        // get the ID of each parent page of the child pages
        $get_parent_page_ID = get_queried_object_id();
        // Get the average score from post_meta of the parent page
        $get_average_score = get_post_meta( $get_parent_page_ID, 'rwp_user_score', true );
        // update each custom field of the childs with the average score data from the post meta of parent page
        update_field('gemiddelde_score_hosting_provider', $get_average_score, $get_child_page_ID);
    }
}
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'when_a_review_gets_submitted' );
add_action('rwp_after_saving_review', 'when_a_review_gets_submitted', 11, 2);
```

**EDIT**
Sorry for not posting debug information:

*Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function when_a_review_gets_submitted(), 1 passed in /var/www/vhosts/domainname.nl/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286 and exactly 2 expected in /var/www/vhosts/domainname.nl/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/hosting-vergelijker/functions.php:452 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/domainname.nl/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): when_a_review_gets_submitted('') #1 /var/www/vhosts/domainname.nl/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 /var/www/vhosts/domainname.nl/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /var/www/vhosts/domainname.nl/httpdocs/wp-includes/template-loader.php(12): do_action('template_redire...') #4 /var/www/vhosts/domainname.nl/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...') #5 /var/www/vhosts/domainname.nl/httpdocs/index.php(17): require('/var/www/vhosts...') #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/domainname.nl/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/hosting-vergelijker/functions.php on line 452*

Comment: First on wp_debug and check what is the error its fatal error which stop your website.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that in the post

Answer (score 0):

`template_redirect` has no more parameters and you passed 2 parameteres which is wrong refer this how to user `template_redirect` hook https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect.

You can't pass `$review, $post_id` in method which is used for `template_redirect` filter.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense... No problems in other install so that is kinda weird but I believe you. Is there a way that I can use template_redirect insite this function?

Comment: what do you want to do in template_redirect  filter? because I don't find any code which actually use for template?

Comment: this function is executed when somebody leaves a review. This function checks on wich page this review is submitted, compares the titles in the query, loops through all child pages of the current page, gets every childs page_ID, gets post meta 'rwp_user_score' and finaly updates the custom field 'gemiddelde_score_hosting_provider' for each child.

This template_redirect action made it work but without it nothing gets updated...